# What type of baker percentage should one use for brown sugar when compared to white sugar?

Tags: bread, sugar, brown-sugar

I was told not to substitute by Brown sugar by weight since it weighs more.

How would I go about substitute then? I saw a few questions addressing this issue, but it does not say the Baker's Percentage and doesn't say how I would go about doing it when compared to white sugar.

Can someone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on what you are baking. What is the recipe for what you are trying to make?

Comment: @GdD Here are the ratios used : Flour 100kg, Water 55 liters, Salt 400 grams, Sugar 2.5 kg, Yeast 1kg.

Comment: What is this recipe for? Bread? Why substitute the sugar?

Comment: When you have the substitution ratio, the percentage follows suit? I get the part about substituting one sugar for the other (although I am not sure whether the sugar is crucial at all), but not the part about the baker’s percentage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be aware that substituting brown for white sugar will result in a different product.  Brown sugar has molasses flavors, and absorbs water differently from white sugar, so both the taste and texture of the final baked goods will be different and no amount of adjusting quantities will change this.

With that in mind, 1 cup of packed brown sugar, weighing 220g, is equivalent to 1 cup of sifted white sugar, weighing 200g, according to the book *Kitchen Companion*.  So in your example recipe, you would swap the 2.5kg white sugar for 2.75kg brown sugar.